# Search bar does not find the action in the Controller in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I type a string inside my search bar and click "Search" it simply does not find my Action in the Controller even though I have named the input the same as the parameter of the action. It returns NotFound with "/Rezulati/Search?searching=Jason+Smith".

View:

```
<div class="col-sm">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Rezulati", FormMethod.Get,
           new { @class = "form-inline" }))
        {
            @Html.TextBox("searching", null,new { @class = "form-control mr-sm-2" })
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        }
 </div>
```

Controller (Named Rezultati):

```
public IActionResult Search(string searching)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(searching))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            searching.Replace(' ', '_');
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var apiUrl = configuration.GetSection("Api").GetSection("Connection").Value + "ironman" + "/" + searching;
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiUrl);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            var response = client.GetAsync(apiUrl).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var convertedString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var rezultati = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TekmovalecIronMancs>>(convertedString.Result);
                return View(rezultati);
            }

            return View(new List<TekmovalecIronMancs>());
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the answer if anyone has the same problem I used this.

```
<form asp-controller="Rezultati" asp-action="Search" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" method="get">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" name="searching">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```